# Hugo fails to build with GitHub Pages because of YAML error

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, hugo

I'm using Hugo on Github Pages, and whenever I push my site to origin, I get this error message sent to my email:

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:
>   There was a YAML syntax error on line 2 column 1 in `<unknown>`: `did not find >expected key while parsing a block mapping`. For more information, see >https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-yaml-in-data-file/.
>   For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>    https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
>   If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this email.

How can I fix this? I heard making a .nojekyll file in root helps, but I don't know how to do that

I've tried some solutions online that didn't work, and I created a nojekyll.nojekyll file in root to hopefully disable Jekyll, if that's the problem...

Comment: Did you check the deploy documentation : https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [.nojekyll](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/) to tell Github to not process your files with Jekyll, so after you build the site, just place a `.nojekyll` file at the root of the `gh-page` or in the `docs` folder.

For example, move all the files generated by Hugo to a `docs` folder and place a `.nojekyll` empty file in `/docs`. Then choose the `docs` folder as the container of the Github pages files and Github will serve those files.

If you want to see a live example, I'm using that approach in this theme https://github.com/marcanuy/simpleit-hugo-theme and works fine, with the resulting website being served at https://marcanuy.github.io/simpleit-hugo-theme/ using the following *[Make](https://github.com/marcanuy/simpleit-hugo-theme/blob/master/Makefile)* recipe to do it automatically:

```
generate-githubpages:
    rm -fr docs && HUGO_ENV=production $(HUGO) --baseURL https://marcanuy.github.io/simpleit-hugo-theme/ --source=exampleSite --themesDir=../.. --config ../config-github-docs.toml && mv exampleSite/public docs && touch docs/.nojekyll
clean:
    rm -fr exampleSite/public/
```

You can read more at Read more at [Publishing your GitHub Pages site from a /docs folder on your master branch](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch)).

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have this problem too! I think the easiest solution is:

1. put your source code into a branch, e.g. source
2. deploy your site on the master branch only.

see how to set this up using github action template for hugo here:  https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages

here is my gh-pages.yaml

3. set source branch

   ```yaml
   name: Publish Site
   on: 
   push:
       branches:
       - source  # default branch
   ```
4. set `publish_branch: master`, or not work

   ```yaml
   - name: Deploy
       uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
       with:
           deploy_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_DEPLOY_KEY }}
           publish_dir: ./public
           publish_branch: master  # deploying branch
   ```